# Handle star * entry in mysql query from shell script

Tags: mysql, shell

I use the following construct in a shell script (using dash, but I think in that case there is no difference to bash):

```
for FIELD in `echo "select column_with_varchar_type from table" | mysql MYDATABASE`
do
    echo "FIELD: $FIELD"
done
```

This works fine for normal strings, but it fails for an entry where star ("*") is in column_with_varchar_type, then dash expands this to use all files in the current working directory which is of course completely wrong.

Is there a way to prevent the shell expansion or replace the star with something else in the mysql-query?

Clarification: I do NOT want to select all columns "select *", but I want to select all entries of one column and one of these entries is a string that is a star. The input to the query **does not contain any stars** and is fine, the problem lies in the output of the query.

For example, if the table contains the strings "aaa", "bbb" and "*", a typical output may be:

```
FIELD: aaa
FIELD: bbb
FIELD: Makefile
FIELD: src
FIELD: some_other_file_that_happens_to_be_in_the_working_directory.txt
```

So I get the strings "aaa" and "bbb" (correct), but "*" is missing and is replaced with whatever garbage is in the working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add quotes in the MySQL-query:

```
for FIELD in `mysql MYDATABASE -e 'select concat(concat("\"", column_with_varchar_type), "\"") from table'`
do
    echo "FIELD: $FIELD"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

### Updated

As discussed in comments, this can be an approach:

```
while read -r field
do
    echo "FIELD: $field"
done < <(echo "select column_with_varchar_type from table" | mysql MYDATABASE)
```

Because the problem was with the data coming from the query, not from the query itself. Hence, it is necessary to handle the strings with `*` that are coming from such query and `while -r` solves it.

---

The problem is that `*` gets expanded by the shell when it is within double quotes.

You can use single quotes instead:

```
for FIELD in $(echo 'select * from table' | mysql MYDATABASE)
do
    do_something
done
```

Note you could also use `-e` option:

```
mysql MYDATABASE -e 'select * from table'
```

Comment: I don't want to select all columns but only one column and one entry in that column is a star.

Comment: OK, my explanation also applies for this: just write all the query within single quotes. If you provide the query you are using, I will update my answer as well. Note when you `do_something`, you also need to use single quotes on what you are doing.

Comment: Of course it does not apply because the echo command is handling the INPUT to the query, but the problem is in the OUTPUT of the query. (And yes, I did check it just in case the $() syntax would work but that also didn't help)

Comment: Then clarify your question, because the way it is stated right now does not help. If the problem is with the `do_something`, indicate what is that something.

Comment: OK, I also added an example - I think it cannot get any clearer than that now.

Comment: Try to give a try to another possible syntax: `while read -r field; do echo "FIELD: $field"; done < <(echo "select column_with_varchar_type from table" | mysql MYDATABASE)`

Comment: I just tried it, it works, but I have bad experiences with while-read constructs (a subshell is opened which cannot change variables of the parent shell so I try to avoid it if possible) - I have also found the solution in the meantime; it is possible to add the quotes in the mysql output. Thank you nevertheless.

Comment: Well the subshell is opened if you pipe. Typical case is to do `cat file | while read...` and yes, in that case you loose the ability to change the values from the original shell. But with this `while` I suggested this won't happen, because there is not such pipe opening a subshell. Anyway, good that you found a solution by providing the output in another manner.

Comment: I tried to do that, but it said that I have to wait 2 days until I can accept my own answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for FIELD in `echo 'select \* from table' | mysql MYDATABASE`
do
    do_something
done
```

Comment: see clarification: Input is fine, input does not contain any stars, the problem lies in the output which does contain an entry that is a string with a single star.